# Typed persistent data structure a la Clojure, done in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure, immutability

In particular an immutable List with a cons operation would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dug around a little bit longer. This library probably comes closest: http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.22/javadoc/index.html . I would imagine that it would be possible to use Clojure's collection classes directly, but I'm not sure if would feel all that natural. (And I don't necessarily need to 'transactional' behaviour.)

Answer (score 2):

There's also a project of "Clojure's data structures modified for use outside of Clojure" at: https://github.com/krukow/clj-ds

Comment: The project seems inactive, however.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a bunch of persistent data structures in Java. My "PersistentList" is pretty close to what you want.

http://code.google.com/p/mikeralib/source/browse/trunk/Mikera/src/mikera/persistent/PersistentList.java

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions posted in [Cons’ing a List in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826246/consing-a-list-in-java). And immutability can be added with:

```
List l;
...
l = Collections.unmodifiableList(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Its collections package has immutable variants for lists, maps, sets, amongst others. The code is easy to use and of high quality.

However, because of implementation details, efficiently consing to a list might not be possible.